# Which is more cost-effective for a mobile backend: Parse or Google Cloud endpoints?

Tags: mobile, backend, google-cloud-endpoints

So me and my partner are working on a mobile app.

And I'be been wondering which mobile backend is a better solution. The problem I see with Parse is that when there are high amounts of traffic in a short period of time, we would need to manually adjust the number of requests per second constantly. And it seems really expensive.

Google Cloud endpoint seems like a good solution, but the api would have to be custom coded and I'm not sure how much it would actually cost.

Then there is Kinver and other services. I'm not sure what code they use, but iv'e heard native code is better than javascript when it comes to making more reliable mobile apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/#cloud-endpoints), Google Cloud Endpoints are completely free. You only will need to pay for your back-end in Google App Engine or in Compute Engine.

But definitely, the prices will be lower than those offered in Parse, except the "free" tier. But once you would need more than 30 request/sec (which is obviously not such a high limit), the prices go up quickly.

Another advantage is that in the Google Cloud you may code your back-end in Java, Python, PHP or Go, or in other languages if you go for the managed VMs option.

Lastly, you would have many other products to use if you need them in the future.